# Hybris commerce - synchronization integration test

Tags: testing, integration, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm beginner in a hybris е-commerce. I need the integration test with synchronization product catalogs, but I have a problem while synchronization. I added new product attribute - "`classification`" and setup value for this attribute in test. Then `performCronJob` method did `syncJob` from `Staged` product catalog, to `Online` product catalog. Now, when got the product from `Online` catalog, it not have value for "`classification`" attribute and occur `AssertionError`. Tell me please, why this happens.  This is my test.

```
@RunWith(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@RunListeners(
{ TransactionRunListener.class, ItemCreationListener.class, LogRunListener.class, PlatformRunListener.class })
@Transactional
public class ProductMyIntegrationTest extends ServicelayerTransactionalTest
{
    @Resource
    private TypeService typeService;
    @Resource
    private ModelService modelService;
    @Resource
    private CatalogVersionService catalogVersionService;
    @Resource
    private ProductService productService;
    @Resource
    private CronJobService cronJobService;

    public ProductService getProductService()
    {
        return productService;
    }

    public CatalogVersionService getCatalogVersionService()
    {
        return catalogVersionService;
    }

    public TypeService getTypeService()
    {
        return typeService;
    }

    public ModelService getModelService()
    {
        return modelService;
    }

    @Test
    public void testProductSyncBehavior()
    {
        final CatalogVersionModel catalogStagedVersionModel = getCatalogVersionService().getCatalogVersion("hybrisProductCatalog",
                "Staged");
        final CatalogVersionModel catalogOnlineVersionModel = getCatalogVersionService().getCatalogVersion("hybrisProductCatalog",
                "Online");
        final Collection<CatalogVersionModel> coll = new ArrayList<>();
        coll.add(catalogOnlineVersionModel);
        coll.add(catalogStagedVersionModel);
        catalogVersionService.setSessionCatalogVersions(coll);

        final ProductModel product = productService.getProduct(catalogStagedVersionModel, "0100");
        product.setClassification("RRRRRRR");
        getModelService().save(product);

        cronJobService.performCronJob((CatalogVersionSyncCronJobModel) modelService.get(PK.fromLong(8796453503477L)), true);

        final ProductModel prodOnline = modelService.get(productService.getProduct(catalogOnlineVersionModel, "0100").getPk());
        final ProductModel prodStaged = modelService.get(productService.getProduct(catalogStagedVersionModel, "0100").getPk());
        Assert.assertNotNull(prodOnline.getClassification());
    }
}
```

AssertionError:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:712)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:722)
    at de.hybris.merchandise.core.product.classification.ProductMyIntegrationTest.testProductSyncBehavior(ProductMyIntegrationTest.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)...
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided my problem. I just extends `ServicelayerTest` without transaction and synchronization successfully. But I not understood why with `Transactional` not work.

Answer (score 0):

Using *@Transactional* means that a transaction is started during the initialization of your test (before *@Before* is executed) and rolled back after your test (after @After is executed), so all data you actually save using the service layer are never committed to the database, that's why you are not able to see the change for your new attribute.

And this seems to be unpredictable since you have no way to be sure the synchronization cronjob would have enough time to synchronize the product before you test your attribute.